# How to adjust all values in a list at the same time (in dart)?

Tags: dart

Say I have the following list:

`List<String> languages = ["dart", "javascript", "coffeescript", "typescript"];`

Now I want to adjust all values in this list at the same time. For example, say that I want to convert each string in this list to uppercase. I can think of a couple of ways to do this. But I'm wondering if I'm missing out on an nicer/easier way to do this.

The way I would do this is:

```
  List<String> languages = ["dart", "javascript", "coffeescript", "typescript"];
  List<String> tempList = [];
  for (String lang in languages) {
    tempList.add(lang.toUpperCase());
  }
  languages = tempList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> languages = ["dart", "javascript", "coffeescript", "typescript"];
print(languages.map((String e) => e.toUpperCase()));
```

Answer (score 2):

```dart
languages.map((e) => e.toUpperCase()).toList();
```

Try at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/43c9bdc49c63f8285e07)

Comment: This does not work, as forEach takes a void function.